# Regex is not displaying correct error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use the validation for the field rate_model.I have used Jquery validate for this. rate_model should accept two types of format

```
1. Number,number (if user enters only two number)
2. Number,number;number,number (if user enters more than two number it should be separated by ; (semicolon) )
```

These are my validation scenarios.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$.validator.addMethod("regex_rate",function(value, element, regexp) {          
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);  });
$("#frm_add_country").validate({
        rules: {
        rate_model: {
            required: true,
            regex_rate:/^([0-9],[0-9])|([0-9],[0-9];)$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        rate_model: {
            required: "Please enter description",            
            regex_rate: "please enter (number,number) or (number,number);(number,number) ",            
        },        
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        console.log("true");
    }
});
});
```

This is my jquery validation

```
<form id="frm_add_country" name="frm_add_country" method="post">
<input type="text" id="rate_model" name="rate_model" class="form-control" >
</form>
```

this is my form filed

```
/^([0-9],[0-9])|([0-9],[0-9];)$/
```

this regular expression is not working for my expected scenarios

Comment: Have a try with: `/^\d+,\d+(?:;\d+,\d+)?$/`

Comment: "Correct" === expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex does the job

```
/^\d+,\d+(?:;\d+,\d+)*$/
```

**Explanation:**

```
/           : regex delimiter
  ^         : begining of string
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
    ,       : a comma
    \d+     : 1 or more digits
    (?:     : start non capture group
      ;     : a semicolumn
      \d+   : 1 or more digits
      ,     : a comma
      \d+   : 1 or more digits
    )*      : end group, 0 or more times
  $         : end of string
/           : regex delimiter
```

Comment: It works but I want that (number,number;) pattern infinite

Comment: @vaibhav: Just replace the quantifier `?` (0 or 1) by `*` (0 or more)

Comment: yes it works.but the number either decimal upto 4 decimal point means 5.4444 this expression or just single digit like 5  in this condition it fails. How can it modify?

Comment: @vaibhav: replace all `\d+` by `[\d.]+`

Answer (score 1):

@toto is correct.
just one correction, if there are still more number like - 
15,16;17,18;19,20 so on
we need to append * as well at the end. So it will be

### */^\d+,\d+(?:;\d+,\d+)*?$*/

Explanation:

```
/           : regex delimiter  
  ^         : beginning of string  
    \d+     : 1 or more digits  
    ,       : a comma  
    \d+     : 1 or more digits  
    (?:     : start non capture group  
      ;     : a semicolon     
      \d+   : 1 or more digits  
      ,     : a comma
      \d+   : 1 or more digits  
     )*     : end group, one or more repetition  
    ?       : optional  
  $         : end of string  
/           : regex delimiter
```